# Prestashop Maintenance mode error

Tags: prestashop, maintenance-mode

First things first I am new to Prestashop.

I have two issues. First is when I'm in the maintenance mode and I add my ip adres to gain access, I still can't access my frontoffice. This gives server error in my Chrome Browser.

But the bigger issue is when I turn the Maintenance mode off (and deleting my IP adress from the list) There is nothing. Just a blank screen. After a little research I found how to turn the error reporting on in defines.inc.php like this:

```
/* Debug only */
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
```

After this I got this error(s):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template "/home/.sites/78/site58/web/modules/categoriesbar/category-bar-level.tpl" on line 8 "{include file=$tpl_dir./category-tree-branch.tpl node=$child last='true'}" - Unexpected "/", expected one of: "{" , "$" , "identifier" , INTEGER' in /home/.sites/78/site58/web/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:665 Stack trace: #0 /home/.sites/78/site58/web/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php(3144): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->trigger_template_error() #1 /home/.sites/78/site58/web/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php(3209): Smarty_Internal_Templateparser->yy_syntax_error(40, '/') #2 /home/.sites/78/site58/web/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_smartytemplatecompiler.php(105): Smarty_Internal_Templateparser->doParse(40, '/') #3 /home/.sites/78/site58/web/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_t in /home/.sites/78/site58/web/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 665
```

any help would be appreciated :)

P.S.
I upgraded the Prestashop from 1.2.x to the 1.5.4 version...
Maybe it has something to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you there is an error in the template. Try changing the line to

```
{include file="$tpl_dir./category-tree-branch.tpl" node=$child last='true'}
```